# Passing Function Pointer of an interface function

Tags: c++, pointers, function-pointers

I have following situation, there are two interfaces:

```
interface ILLShapeAttribute
{
  virtual void DefineAttribute(const char* pszAttributeName, VARIANT* pvAttributeData) = 0;
};

interface ILLShapeNotification
{
  virtual bool IsUsed(const RECT& rcBounds) = 0;
    virtual void DefineAttribute(const char* pszAttributeName, VARIANT* pvAttributeData) = 0;
}
```

And 2 functions:

```
INT LlShapeGetAttributeList(LPCWSTR pwszShapefileName, ILLShapeAttribute* pIAttrInfo);
INT LlShapeEnumShapes(LPCWSTR pwszShapefileName, ILLShapeNotification* pIInfo);
```

In those both functions I want to call the same function `IterateRecords2` which should get the pointer to the function DefineAttribute, e.g. `ILLShapeAttribute::DefineAttribute` and `ILLShapeNotification::DefineAttribute`

I defined it this way:

```
void IterateRecords2(ifstream& file, void (*pDefineAttribute)(const char*, VARIANT*))
{
  pDefineAttribute(NULL, NULL); //will be called with real values
}
```

Until now the code compiles and everythig is fine. But then I try to call the `IterateRecords2` like

```
IterateRecords2(file, pIAttrInfo->DefineAttribute);
```

or

```
IterateRecords2(file, pIInfo->DefineAttribute);
```

I get the compiler error:

```
error C3867: 'ILLShapeAttribute::DefineAttribute': function call missing argument list; use '&ILLShapeAttribute::DefineAttribute' to create a pointer to member
```

**Please:** I know, that ILLShapeNotification could inherit from ILLShapeAttribute and then pass *ILLShapeAttribute instead of function pointer but I want to understand how it works.

**Question:** how can I pass the pointer to `DefineAttribute` to `IterateRecords2`?

Comment: Since when does c++ has an interface? is it not still using abstact classes only?

Comment: @omerschleifer It's probably a Microsoft extension of some sort.

Comment: @Angew I suppose it is a macro , just wanted to make sure

Comment: @doctorlove this is not COM, not C++/CLI etc. It's just C++.

Comment: @omerschleifer don't know since then, but I was able to declare interfaces in C++ in Visual Studio 6.0, so probably pretty long.

Comment: @VladL: I guess *Omer* uses "C++" for "standard C++". ;)

Comment: @VladL, `interface` is not "just C++"

Comment: @JonathanWakely I don't know if interface modifier is specified for ANSI C++ as I write programms for windows using Visual Studio. I just wanted to avoid assumptions and answers like, "you used inerface so it's c++/cli lets discuss that ...". So to be more clear, It's a normal VS C++ project, maybe not ansi, but still, **not another language, not another technology**.

Comment: [`interface`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/50h7kwtb%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) is an MS extension, it's not ISO C++, but apparently it doesn't change any semantics, just enforces some restrictions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Question:** how can I pass the pointer to `DefineAttribute` to `IterateRecords2`?

You can't.

A pointer-to-member-function is not compatible with a pointer to function, and even if it was, you'd need an object to call it on, you can't just call a member function without an object.

Some options are:

**1)** Take a pointer-to-member-function and pass an object.

This would solve your compiler error, but to be able to pass different types of object that are not related by inheritance you would need `IterateRecords2` to be a template:

```
template<typename T>
void IterateRecords2(ifstream& file, T* obj, void (T::*pDefineAttribute)(const char*, VARIANT*))
{
  obj->pDefineAttribute(NULL, NULL);
}
```

Now you can use it like this:

```
IterateRecords2(file, pIAttrInfo, &ILLShapeAttribute::DefineAttribute);
```

or:

```
IterateRecords2(file, pIInfo, &ILLShapeNotification::DefineAttribute);
```

**2)** Bind an object and its member function into a callable type, and pass that:

```
void IterateRecords2(ifstream& file, std::function<void(const char*, VARIANT*)> DefineAttribute)
{
  DefineAttribute(NULL, NULL);
}
```

Then call it like:

```
IterateRecords2(file, std::bind(&ILLShapeAttribute::DefineAttribute, pIAttrInfo));
```

If you can't use `std::function` and `std::bind` you can replace them with `boost::function` and `boost::bind`